# Comparison operator overloading, why doesn't the compiler do the work?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

Today I was implementing a datatype, in which I decided to overload the comparison operators. While doing this, a question popped into my head.

Why do I, as a programmer, have to define every single comparison operator, when all I do, is to define them in terms of `'<'` (see below)? - That is, why doesn't the compiler automatically generate these for me.

```
a == b    =>    !(a<b || b<a)
a != b    =>     (a<b || b<a)
a > b     =>    b < a
a >= b    =>    !(a < b)
a <= b    =>    !(b < a)
```

I do understand, that it is perfectly reasonable for performance reasons, to want to implement more than just `'<'`.

I know the obvious answer is, that it's because I can easily do it myself, but I do believe that compilers/language specifications should do whatever possible to ease using the language.

Comment: The interaction with other operators would probably be quite complex and error prone. The types on both sides need not necessarily be the same, and then there are people who would want != be implemented in terms of ==, and then there are cases where the user definition is visible in some TUs, but not others, which would then easily violate the ODR and so on. Its probably easier and less error prone to use stuff like the boost operator.

Comment: The first two identities are only valid if `<` defines a *total ordering*. For many types, such an ordering is impossible to define, but you might still want `<` to define a *partial ordering*, since that makes the type easy to use with standard containers and algorithms. You would then want to define `==` separately to test actual equality, not just equivalence under the ordering.

Comment: @Dukeling: If you do not believe that the standard/compiler should do whatever it can to ease implementing software, would you opt against having the typedefs as well?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I do believe you answer my question, as to whether `==` can be defined in terms of `<`, and Pete Becker and timrau answered the remainder of the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Skeen There's a big difference between "whatever possible" and "some stuff". C++ is reasonably low level, giving you lots of freedom. Ease of use is often a conflicting goal to this end.

Comment: @Dukeling: We can agree on that, there's a difference, but I don't see how this specific feature would effect your freedom, and if it would indeed, then why the standard agree on including `std::rel_ops`?

Comment: @Skeen: For the reason @MikeSeymour mentioned, any `<` relation you define would have to be a total ordering. This is quite a heavy restriction on `<`. `std::rel_ops` is optional and doesn't affect you if you don't use it, as is C++ tradition.

Comment: @Skeen Nothing is forcing you to use those either, you're still free to define all of them as you wish, but that is the mathematically correct way of defining the operators (assuming total ordering). Oh and the reason your first two aren't there is because equality shouldn't be defined in terms of less-than / greater-than, likely mainly for performance and because some objects may have **no** logical ordering, but equality is well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `operator<()` and `operator==()`, and

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std::rel_ops;
```

Then all comparison operators are automatically defined.
See the example provided by [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp)

Comment: Why do I need to provide both? - doesn't `a == b => !(a<b || b<a)` fulfill the typical reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties of equalities?

Comment: @Skeen I would guess it could be more efficient to implement `==` without two invocations of `<`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I know, that's likely more efficient, but then again it could also be the case that implementing `>=` for itself, would be quicker than in terms of `<`. However I do believe @Mike Seymour is on to something.

Comment: This will work only in simple toy examples. The lookup rules are not as simple as they may seem, and if there is any overload of `operator<` found *before* lookup hits the global namespace (common ancestor of `::std` and any of your namespaces) it won't look into `std::rel_ops` and it won't find this

Answer (score 3):

Read about `std::rel_ops`. Nobody uses it.

Comment: `std::rel_ops` is broken. I cannot think how that could possibly work. If a tag type was added to the namespace, then you could control in your type whether to use the default implementation by means of tagging your type through inheritance, and letting ADL find those templates. Without it, `std::rel_ops` is either useless or hard to use (on the assumption I cannot make it work, it is hard at least for me)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - as I said, nobody uses it. `<g>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [boost::operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/operators.htm). It does exactly what you want and much more.